# Specifying the exact number of bins for plotting a histogram in plotly

Tags: python, histogram, plotly, binning

As per the online documentation, `xbins` takes a dictionary as input such as `xbins=dict(start, end, size)` along with `autobinx=False` for specifying the exact number of bins, however this does not work for me.

Assigning `size = df[col].shape[0]/100` or `df[col].shape[0]/10` returns the same plot, where `df[col].shape[0] = 249`

I also tried to input size as a float between 0 to 1, however the histograms produced are the same for different values.

I am aware of the use of `nbinsx` but I want to specify the exact number of bins.